# Sequelize mysql reads timezone incorrectly from mysql database

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, sequelize.js

I'm using sequelize in node.js application and mysql as a database but the problem is, when I read data from the MySQL table, the timezone is read incorrectly.

I want to use **IST(Indian Standard Time) or 'Asia/Calcutta'** as a timezone for both reading and writing to the MySQL database.

I've tried this [Sequelize reads datetime in UTC only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47367893/sequelize-reads-datetime-in-utc-only) configuration **but the problem is solved partially i.e. only for writing to database.** **But, it still exists while reading the date-time from database.**

**See, the configuration below to understand it better. I've also attached screenshot of incorrect timezone read from the DB.**

**Version Details:**
"mysql2": "^2.3.0",
"sequelize": "^6.6.5"

[image: incorrect-timezone-img]

**Table Structure in Mysql Database:**
[image: invoice-table-structure]

**Table data with correct date and time.**
[image: invoice-table-with-correct-datetime]

**`Note:`** The issue is only in reading the DateTime from the database and not for storing.

**Sequelize Model Class:**

```js
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const Invoice = sequelize.define('Invoice', {
        invoiceId: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
            allowNull: false,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true
        },

        invoiceNumber: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER(6).UNSIGNED.ZEROFILL,
            allowNull: false,
            unique: true
        }, 

        description: {
            type: DataTypes.TEXT,
            allowNull: false
        },

        discount: {
            type: DataTypes.DECIMAL(9,2),
            allowNull: false,
            defaultValue: 0.00
        },

        invoiceTotal: {
            type: DataTypes.DECIMAL(9,2),
            allowNull: false,
            defaultValue: 0.00
        },

        paymentTotal: {
            type: DataTypes.DECIMAL(9,2),
            allowNull: false,
            defaultValue: 0.00
        },

        invoiceDate: {
            type: DataTypes.DATE,
            defaultValue: DataTypes.NOW,
            allowNull: false
        }

    }, {
        underscored: true // will add underscore in field name of database instead of storing camel case notation in db
    });

    Invoice.associate = function (model) {
        Invoice.belongsTo(model.Customer, {
            foreignKey: {
                name: "cust_id",
                allowNull: false
            } 
        });
    };

    return Invoice;
}
```

```js
const sequelize = new Sequelize(
    config.get('db.database'),  // reading from configuration file
    config.get('db.user'), 
    config.get('db.password'), {
        host: config.get('db.host'), 
        dialect: 'mysql',
        dialectOptions: {
            useUTC: false, //for reading from database
            dateStrings: true,
            typeCast: function (field, next) { // for reading from database
            if (field.type === 'DATETIME') {
              return field.string()
            }
            return next()
          },
        },
        timezone: 'Asia/Calcutta'
});
```

Comment: Which MySQL version? Have you [populated the database timezones](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/time-zone-support.html#time-zone-installation)? What datatype does sequelize make the `invoiceDate` column (`show create table Invoice`)?

Comment: Have you tried all of the answers posted in the question you linked or you've just tried the accepted answer? Furthermore, if you read the comments on the accepted answer, one user seem to have (maybe) a similar issue as yours, in which the user conclusion is "not to use sequelize in the future"... (I'm not implying that you should give up trying to achieve it with sequelize though).

Comment: The datatype for the `invoiceDate` field in my sequelize model class is `DATE` and in database table the datatype stored by MySQL is `DATETIME`.  To help you more, kindly see the image above of invoice table structure in database and Sequelize Model class in node js.

Comment: The answer to your 2nd question i.e. Have I populated the database timezones? - So, I'm not aware of this. Can you kindly elaborate this a bit for me?

Comment: @FanoFN, yes I've tried almost all the answers posted in the question I linked above. Even, I've read the comments and tried that too. Yes, I read the conclusion of a user about giving up on using sequelize but how can we give up if we're stuck in the middle of our application? - Instead, finding the solution is a better option I believe.

Comment: I agree with you, that's why I said I'm not implying you to do so. It's just a pity that the user did not find any solution in their part that they had to give up. Which makes the issue unresolved (for that particular user).

Answer (score 2):

To your surprise, I've an answer to this query **but again this solution has a little problem in it.** Let me tell you the problem first.

**`Problem:`** In my application when I create the new invoice, I go ahead and save it in the MySQL database with the date and time values. But, what I get in a response is a correct date but wrong time. So, this is the real problem that still exists in my application. And, this doesn't matter to me because I am not displaying the date and time of retrieved response. You check with your usecase.

**`Solution:`** I've a use case in my application where I retrieve all the invoices with their date and time and here I get the correct date and time from the MySQL database. So, this is enough for me as of now. Check the below configuration for this purpose.

```js
const sequelize = new Sequelize(
    config.get('db.database'), 
    config.get('db.user'), 
    config.get('db.password'), {
        host: config.get('db.host'),
        dialect: 'mysql',
        define: {
            underscored: true, // use underscore in table name
        },
        dialectOptions: {
            useUTC: false, //for reading from database
            dateStrings: true,
            typeCast: true
        },
        timezone: 'Asia/Calcutta'
});
```

[image: correct date and time]

Comment: Hi! Have you found the solution for this? I have the same exact problem. In MySQL table is UTC+7, but what sequelize read is UTC+0

Comment: @HenryGunawan try this configuration for your usecase https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47367893/sequelize-reads-datetime-in-utc-only