# default timezone is not working for sequelize querys in mysql

Tags: mysql, timezone, sequelize.js

I set the timezone when I create the connection with sequelize but is not working in any query.

Here is my config code

```
  DB_CONFIG: {
    dialect: 'mysql',
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    username: 'root',
    password: '******',
    database: '******',
    omitNull: true,
    dialectOptions: {
      useUTC: false, //for reading from database
      timezone: '+08:00'
    },
    timezone: '+08:00' //for writing to database
  }
```

The table model

```
const { DataTypes } = require('sequelize')
const sequelize = require('./db')

const attributes = {
  id: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true,
    allowNull: false
  },
  givenName: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  },
  courtesyName: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
  },
  parentId: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER
  },
  generation: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false
  },
  birth: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
  },
  death: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
  },
  memo: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
  }
}

module.exports = sequelize.define('master', attributes)
```

The query result:

```
"updatedAt": "2022-11-08T02:31:22.381Z",
"createdAt": "2022-11-08T02:31:22.381Z"
```

they are still 00:00 timezone, not +08:00 timezone.

How can I configure it correctly？

Comment: What are the database structures for these fields?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I just found a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70828656/sequelize-mysql-reads-timezone-incorrectly-from-mysql-database

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sequelize mysql reads timezone incorrectly from mysql database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70828656/sequelize-mysql-reads-timezone-incorrectly-from-mysql-database)