# How to get time in IST using Sequelise.fn function?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, backend

I am using sequelize.fn("NOW") to get the time at which the database is updated but it is according to the UTC standard whereas I want the time in IST standard . I did try doing this:
useUTC:false, timezone:"+5:30" , but it is not working. Any leads appreciated.
thanks

I tried this in the sequelize initialisation :
useUTC:false, timezone:'+5:30'

but i am getting the time in UTC only

Comment: store timestamps in UTC, but when you want to perform some operation call `.toLocaleString(undefined, { timeZone: "Asia/Kolkata" })` , [ref1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString).

Comment: do you mean this:  sequelize.fn('NOW').toLocaleString(undefined, { timeZone: "Asia/Kolkata" }) ?

Comment: try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47367893/sequelize-reads-datetime-in-utc-only

Comment: Ignoring invalid configuration option passed to Connection: useUTC. This is currently a warning, but in future versions of MySQL2, an error will be thrown if you pass an invalid configuration option to a Connection

Comment: but i am getting the above error