Sequelize - PostgreSQL timezone won't change
I can't use anything else but UTC when reading a Date datatype.
Here's my object to be added to PostgreSQL db:
{
    "word": "test",
    "wordLanguage": "eng",
    "testDate": "2024-07-08T15:00:00+03:00"
}

When I try to read this data here's what I receive:
{
    "id": 8,
    "word": "test",
    "wordLanguage": "eng",
    "testDate": "2024-07-08T12:00:00.000Z",
    "updatedAt": "2024-07-08T15:20:17.906Z",
    "createdAt": "2024-07-08T15:20:17.906Z"
}

What I want to receive is it should be in GMT+3. So "testDate" should be 15:00 not 12:00.
My model:
sequelize.define('Word', {
  word: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
  },
  wordLanguage: {
    type: DataTypes.ENUM,
    allowNull: false,
    values: ['eng', 'tr'],
  },
  testDate: {
    type: DataTypes.DATE,
    allowNull: false,
  },
}) 

My Sequelize connection constructor:
const sequelize = new Sequelize('db123', 'user123', 'password123', {
  host: 'db',
  port: 5432,
  dialect: 'postgres',
  timezone: 'Europe/Istanbul',
  dialectOptions: {
    useUTC: false,
  },
  logging: true,
});

Also when I run show timezone in dbeaver the result is:

System date:
# date
Mon Jul  8 06:25:18 PM +03 2024

So everything is configured to GMT+3 why I still receive results as UTC and how to fix it?

Start logging all your SQL statements and check what is sent to the database.

So do you think my config looks ok?

I don't think at all, I would start by looking at the facts. Your config is your intention, but that might be different from the facts. show timezone gives you the timezone for that database connection. Start a second connection using a different timezone and you will have a different fact, for the same database. That's why you have to collect all SQL statements that are sent to the database.

Also just to be sure try the query show timezone using Sequelize raw query

@Anatoly It returns [ { TimeZone: 'Europe/Istanbul' } ]

@FrankHeikens db-1       | 2024-07-09 14:28:43.145 +03 [66] LOG:  execute <unnamed>: INSERT INTO "Words" ("id","word","wordLanguage","testDate","createdAt","updatedAt") VALUES (DEFAULT,$1,$2,$3,$4,$5) RETURNING "id","word","wordLanguage","testDate","createdAt","updatedAt"; db-1       | 2024-07-09 14:28:43.145 +03 [66] DETAIL:  parameters: $1 = 'test', $2 = 'eng', $3 = '2024-07-08 12:00:00+03', $4 = '2024-07-09 14:28:43.133+03', $5 = '2024-07-09 14:28:43.133+03'

Also the returning object is {     "id": 16,     "word": "test",     "wordLanguage": "eng",     "testDate": "2024-07-08T09:00:00.000Z",     "updatedAt": "2024-07-09T11:28:43.133Z",     "createdAt": "2024-07-09T11:28:43.133Z" }

Maybe it is duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47367893/sequelize-reads-datetime-in-utc-only?
